# >> operator overloading...C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm just a new to C++ And i'm at the beginning...Just want some help...would be appreciate it if somebody can explain where am I wrong with this:
First of all my Time.h code:

```
#ifndef TIME_H
#define TIME_H
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class time {
    friend istream &operator>> (istream &, time);
private:
    int hour;
    int minute;
    int second;

public:
    time(int = 0, int = 0, int = 0);
    void settime(int, int, int);
    void sethour(int);
    void setminute(int);
    void setsecond(int);
};

#endif
```

And now, Time.cpp:

```
#include<iostream>
#include"Time.h"
using namespace std;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

time::time(int h, int m, int s)
{
    settime(h, m, s);
}
void time::settime(int hr, int min, int sec)
{
    sethour(hr);
    setminute(min);
    setsecond(sec);
}
void time::sethour(int h)
{
    hour = (h >= 0 && h < 24) ? h : 0;
}
void time::setminute(int m)
{
    minute = (m >= 0 && m < 60) ? m : 0;
}
void time::setsecond(int s)
{
    second = (s >= 0 && s < 60) ? s : 0;
}
istream &operator>> (istream &in, time m)
{
    in >> m.sethour >> m.setminute >> m.setsecond;
}
```

And finally source.cpp:

```
#include<iostream>
#include"D:\headers\Time.h"
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    time t;
    cin >> t;
    system("pause");
}
```

But when I compile it, it gives me an error:
    1.Error C3867   'time::sethour': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member Project33   D:\headers\Time.cpp
2.Error C2679   binary '>>': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable conversion)    Project33   D:\headers\Time.cpp
 Can anybody help me out???

Comment: If you pass an argument by value to a function, what happens to that argument? What happens when you try to modify the argument? Will that modification be reflected in the code calling your function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sethour` is a member function not a member variable. You need to use a variable.

You can use:

```
istream &operator>> (istream &in, time m)
{
   return (in >> m.hour >> m.minute >> m.second);
}
```

However, that won't do the calling function any good because you are changing a copy. You need to pass `m` by reference.

```
istream &operator>> (istream &in, time& m)
{
   return (in >> m.hour >> m.minute >> m.second);
}
```

Make sure to change the declaration accordingly.

Had the function not been a friend of the class, you could use:

```
istream &operator>> (istream &in, time& m)
{
   // Read the data.
   int hour;
   int minute;
   int second;
   in >> m.hour >> m.minute >> m.second;

   // Set the member values using function calls.
   m.sethour(hour);
   m.setminute(minute);
   m.setsecond(second);

   return in;
}
```

Comment: @shahid-e-gomnam, glad I would help.

Comment: It worked...Much appreciate it man...Just doesn't it supposed to be set whit sethour& etc...cause somebody says it is always safer to access private members from public methods...Can you explain this a bit for me?

Answer (score 1):

You're reading into functions here:

```
in >> m.sethour >> m.setminute >> m.setsecond;
        ^            ^              ^
```

That's a simple typo. The bigger problem is that you take the `time` by value, which prevents any modifications from it to propagating; you probably wanted to take a reference there.